# How can I get a regex match on a phrase that also includes a word I want to match on?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the following regex to match specific phrases so I can highlight them on a web page:

```
/phrase\b(?!^\s*)/g
```

Where phrase is one of four strings: "Background Language", "First Language", "Second Language" and "Language".

"Language" is being matched in all cases, but I only want it to match if it's not preceded by "Background", "First" or "Second". So anywhere "Background Language" occurs on the web page, it should be highlighted, and the same for the "First Language" and "Second Language". At the moment only "Language" is highlighted.

I'm thinking I need to do a look behind with my regex but don't know how to accomplish this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Matches "Language" only if is not preceded by "Background, First or Second".

```js
let str =  "Background Language, First Language, Second Language, Language"
let regex = /(?<!Background | First | Second )Language/g;
console.log(str.match(regex));
```

Matches "Language" only if is preceded by "Background, First or Second".

```js
let str =  "Background Language, First Language, Second Language, Language"
let regex = /(?:Background | First | Second )Language/g;
console.log(str.match(regex));
```